# Contractible vs. Contractible in a space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am reading Introduction to Homotopy Theory by Arkowitz Martin and on page 9 it reads:

---

*More generally, if $A$ is a subset of $X$ with inclusion map $i : A \to X$; then $A$ is
contractible in $X$ if $i$ is nullhomotopic.*

---

So if $S^1$ being the unit circle naturally embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $S^1$ is contractible in $\mathbb{R}^2$? (There is a linear homotopy from the natural embedding to the constant map to the orgin of $\mathbb{R}^2$)

Obviously $S^1$ itself is not contractible. Then intuitively what does "$S^1$ is contractible in $\mathbb{R}^2$" mean?

Comment: Any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible, since we can always write down a "shrinking" homotopy that collapses $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the origin. The key difference between $S^1$ regarded as a space on its own, and $S^1$ regarded as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has points to "fill in the hole" in the center of $S^1$.

Comment: *Contractible in X* seems to mean precisely that: That $i$ is nullhomotopic. On the other hand if the identity $1_A:A\to A$ is nullhomotopic (through maps $A\to A$), then $A$ is *contractible*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bongers said, any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible.

"$S^1$ is contractible in $\mathbb{R}^2$" just means that the circle $S^1$ indeed can be contracted to the origin in the plane as you said.